# Poincare Inequality implies Equivalent Norms

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

I am currently working through the subject of Sobolev Spaces using the book 'Partial Differential Equations' by Lawrence Evans. After the result proving the Poincare Inequality it says the following in the book(page 266.) "In view of the Poincare Inequality, on $W_{0}^{1,p}(U)$ the norm $||DU||_{L^{p}}$ is equivalent to $||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}$, if $U$ is bounded." Do you know the argument behind this statement?

Comment: I can't understand why do you accepted Alex answers if he gives you only a partial answer (also to complicated).

Comment: I don't understand why you think it is a partial answer? It seems fine to me. He is doing it using results from Evans book.

Comment: He considered only the case $1\leq p< n$, while Julian proof is valid for all cases.

Comment: Yes I agree Julien's is simpler and stronger answer seeing as it is more general. The Remark in Evans is referring to that particular case of $1 \leq p < n$. I just ticked Alex's because he used the proofs presented in Evans up until that point, so it followed well in the sequence in which I am studying it. But I indicated 'useful answer for both'. I think Julien made a type though, it should be $||Du||_{L^{p}(U)} \leq ||Du||_{L^{p}(U)} + ||u||_{L^{p}(U)} = ||u||_{W_{0}^{1,p}(U)} \leq ||Du||_{L^{p}(U)} + C||Du||_{L^{p}(U)}$.

Comment: Ok, in the end you are aware that the inequality is valid for all $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies to $1 \leq p < n$. You want constants $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ such that $B_{1}||u||_{W_{0}^{1,p}(U)} \leq ||Du||_{L^{p}(U)} \leq B_{2}||u||_{W_{0}^{1,p}}$. The inequality $||Du||_{L^{p}(U)} \leq B_{2}||u||_{W_{0}^{1,p}}$ is trivial.

From Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev Inequality we have:
$||u||_{L^{p*}(U)} \leq C||Du||_{L^{p}(U)}$ where $p* := \frac{np}{n-p}$ $p* > p$.

We also have $||u||_{L^{q}(U)} \leq C||u||_{L^{p*}(U)}$ if $1\leq q \leq p*$ by Generalized Holder Inequality.

If we take $A = \frac{1}{c^{2}}$ and $q=p$ then we have $A||u||_{L^{p}} \leq ||Du||_{L^{p}}$ then since $||u||_{W_{0}^{1,p}} \leq A||u||_{L^{p}} + A||Du||_{L^{p}} \leq (1+A)||Du||_{L^{p}}$ it follows that $\frac{A}{A+1}||u||_{W_{0}^{1,p}} \leq ||Du||_{L^{p}}$

Take $B_{1} := \frac{A}{A+1}$.

The result follows from combining the two inequalities.

Comment: Let $U$ bounded, and $p^*= \frac{np}{n-p}$ and $n>p$, then

$W^{1,p}(U) \subset L^{p^{*}}(U)$
This inclusion is not compact. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 5):

$$
\|Du\|_{L^p(U)} \le \|Du\|_{L^p(U)}+\|u\|_{L^p(U)} = \|u\|_{W_0^{1,p}(U)} \le (1+C)\,\|Du\|_{L^p(U)}
$$
where $C$ is the constant in Poincare's inequality.

Comment: Dear @Julián, I think it is good to correct the typo in your answer: $\|Du\|_{L^p(U)}+\|u\|_{L^p(U)}=\|u\|_{W_0^{1,p}(U)}$ instead of $\|Du\|_{L^p(U)}+\|u\|_{L^p(U)}=\|Du\|_{W_0^{1,p}(U)}$. This may cause some confusion in the beginners.

Comment: @Tomás Thank you for your comment. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Dear @Julián, sorry to bother you again, but you have changed to wrong place.

Comment: @Tomás I should not work at "siesta" time. Thanks again.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Let $U$ bounded, and $p^*= \frac{np}{n-p}$ and $n>p$, then

$W^{1,p}(U) \subset L^{p^{*}}(U)$
This inclusion is not compact. Can someone tell me why?